# While Exporting schema using oracle expdp getting directory invalid error

Tags: oracle, database-administration

There are around 5 schemas on my Oracle database (version 19c) that I want to export using expdp utility and have followed the below steps while exporting data from my_schema:

1. `sqlplus / as sysdba`
2. `create directory prf_dir as '/home/oracle/Export Full';`
3. `grant read, write on directory prf_dir to prf_schema;`
4. `grant datapump_exp_full_database to prf_schema;`
5. `exit`
6. `expdp prf_schema/Password1@pdb_1 DIRECTORY=prf_dir DUMPFILE=prf_schema_dump.dmp LOGFILE=prf_schema_dump.log schemas=prf_schema;`

But I am getting below errors:

```
ORA-39002:  invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file
ORA-39087: directory name prf_dir is invalid.
```

Prior check:

1. I have checked the valid directories using `dba_directory` and could see my directory over there.
2. I have checked permission on the path `/home/oracle/Export Full` and it's 777.
3. Prior to this I performed the same activity for another schema which is `app_schema` in the same path and for that, it got successfully executed with the steps I mentioned above but when trying to do the same thing by just changing the schema name it throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it is about a **space** in directory name.

Try to rename it from `Export Full` to `export_full` and then

```
create directory prf_dir as '/home/oracle/export_full';
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried removing the space while creating a directory and given path which contains folder name without space but still got the same error.

Comment: Error says that Oracle is "Unable to open the log file" because "directory name prf_dir is invalid". Log file name is "prf_schema_dump.log" (looks OK, nothing strange about it) so - if directory is now valid - that *should* work. What does `select * from all_directories` return?

Comment: This returns 
Owner Directory_name Directory_path origin_con_id
SYS       PRF_DIR              /home/oracle/export_full  0

Sorry for the above text. I am not sure how to keep that content in table.

Comment: No problem, comments can't keep formatting. Directory name suggests that this is ... what? Linux? Does operating system user (who "owns" Oracle software) have **write** privileges (on **operating system level**) on /home/oracle/export_full directory?

Comment: Yes, I am using MobaXterm which uses Linux. I am not sure whether it has write privileges or not but it worked for other schema and I followed the same steps.

Comment: Hm, so how is PRF_SCHEMA different from others (where export works OK)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255325/discussion-between-vicky-and-littlefoot).